# Jquery ajax request not able to return data to other function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am making a simple ajax request using jquery . Below is my ajax function .

```
     var makeJqueryAjaxRequest = function(arrParam) {
         var request = $.ajax({
             url : arrParam['url'],
             async: false,
             type: arrParam['type'],
             data: arrParam['data'],
             dataType: arrParam['data_type'],
             success: function(data) {
                 if(data){ 
                 return data;   
                 }
             }
         });
     }
```

here is my function calls :

```
      var items = {
       "type" : 'POST',
       "url" : ajaxGetUrl,
       "data" : arrParam['data'],
       "data_type" : 'html'
      };
      var msg = makeJqueryAjaxRequest(items);
```

Now don't know why my  makeJqueryAjaxRequest function  always returns the null value. If I alert the data in the success : I'm getting the data perfect . But when I try to return it gives me the null value

Comment: You can't  return value from an `Asynchronous` function. This has been answered many times. You have to use a callback function.

Comment: @joy thanks :) i am new to jquery.it would be a great help  can u give me a example of callback function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You can't return value from an Asynchronous callback function.

Because `success` is a `async` callback which is called by jQuery when a [ajax Event(success in this case)](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) fires. So returning something from this functions will not have any effect as they will be returned to jQuery code.

You can use the following

```
var makeJqueryAjaxRequest = function(arrParam) {
     var request = $.ajax({
        url : arrParam['url'],
        async: false,
        type: arrParam['type'],
        data: arrParam['data'],
        dataType: arrParam['data_type']

     });
   return request;
  }
```

Then do

```
 makeJqueryAjaxRequest(items).done(function(data){
    if(data){
      var msg  = data;  
      // do whatever you like with msg now
    }
 });
```

---

**Alternative Callback Approach:**

```
var makeJqueryAjaxRequest = function(arrParam,callback) {
     var request = $.ajax({
        url : arrParam['url'],
        async: false,
        type: arrParam['type'],
        data: arrParam['data'],
        dataType: arrParam['data_type'],
        success: function(data) {
           if(data){ 
              callback(data); 
           }
       }
     });

  }
```

Then use it like

```
 makeJqueryAjaxRequest(items,function(data){
    // do whatever you like with data
 });
```

Doc on [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Note**

And with either of these approach `async: false` is not necessary. You can remove that. As the doc says

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of **async: false** is deprecated