# jQuery doing jobs after $.get data getting finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop JavaScript until the `$.get` finish its job. I'm using `while` to do that. this is my code:

```
function process() {
    var s = false;
    var text = "";
    var xs = oxl.join(",");
    var ys = oyl.join(",");
    $.post(processUrl, {
        xl: xs,
        yl: ys,
        text: text
    }, function(data) {
        text = data;
        s = true;
    });
    while (!s);
    return text;
}
```

but the code doesn't finish the `while` and it hangs. I want to know how can I return the text **after** `$.post` completed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery ajax request not able to return data to other function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223356/jquery-ajax-request-not-able-to-return-data-to-other-function)

Comment: You have to follow asynchronous ajax nature, otherwise your clients will get their browser frozen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't wait activly use a callback to signal your `process` method is finished:

```
function process(callback) {
    var xs = oxl.join(",");
    var ys = oyl.join(",");
    $.post(processUrl, {
        xl: xs,
        yl: ys,
        text: text
    }, function(data) {
      if ($.isFunction(callback))
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

And where you call `process` you can use it like this:

```
process(function (text) { /* do something with text */ }
```

Comment: Also it worth mentioning to check if `callback` is a valid callback using `$.isFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$.ajax` instead and set the `async` option:

```
$.ajax({
     async: false,
     url: ...,
     success: function(result) {
         ...
     }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Please stop recommending `async`. 1) it is deprecated 2) it is **TERRIBLE** practice

Comment: @zerkms I read the jQuery track, and according to it `async` is still valid in the sense of: `$.ajax({async: false, ... }).then(...);` or did I miss something? http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11013#comment:40

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks."

Comment: @zerkms is it not deprecated "The $.ajax method with async: false is supported but you must use a callback parameter rather than a Promise method such as .then or .done."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't finish because the while loop blocks everything else, so it can't run any other functions. It is not multi-threaded.

You can use async, but it is deprecated. If you make it synchronous, your GUI is likely to be blocked, especially if it is using javascript.

You should use callbacks for whatever you need to do. Refactor your code so that whatever you wanted to do with the return value, do it in the callback.